# Filtering errors in Sentry

Tags: django, sentry

I'm running sentry.io for my django project. I'd like to prevent a certain error from being reported so as to not consume my quota.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to find any code samples on how to do this. Sentry's documentation doesn't clearly outline how to do this (at least it's not clear to me).

I was wondering if you'd be able to provide a simple example or point me in the right direction.

I'm on the Developer plan, so I need to filter these errors server side before sending to Sentry in order to prevent my quota from being hit.

Update: I see that I can filter out errors using this code:

```
import sentry_sdk

def before_send(event, hint):
    if something == True:
       return None

    return event

sentry_sdk.init(before_send=before_send)
```

https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/python/configuration/filtering/

The error shows up in Sentry as OSError. I'd like to ignore anything with this title, but I'm not quite sure how to write this logic into the function above.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify [sample_rate](https://docs.sentry.io/clients/python/advanced/) parameter in your settings to skip part of events.

So, you can send only 10% of events like this

```
sentry_sdk.init(
    dsn=SENTRY_DSN,
    integrations=[DjangoIntegration()],
    send_default_pii=True,
    sample_rate=0.1,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. There is a specific error that i'd like to ignore though. It's title is OSERROR

Comment: @JasonHoward [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57828717/how-to-ignore-certain-python-errors-from-sentry-capture) should help

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a shot